# Nginx forward with URL rewrite and proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, nginx-location, proxypass, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am looking for help in nginx configuration while forwarding request to another domain .

**Proxy scenarios:**

```
https://service1.com/downloads -> https://service2.com/app/downloads 

https://service1.com/downloads?param1=a&param2=b -> https://service2.com/app/downloads?param1=a&param2=b
```

Browser should have left side URL(service1) all the time.
But Service 2 endpoints are different, it has additional param 'app'.

I  have done this without considering 'app' param in service 2 endpoints using below config:

```
location /downloads {
    set $upstream_endpoint https://service2.com;
    proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint;
  }
```

But i need help, when i want to append some addition param ('app') while calling service2 endpoint.

I am trying with rewrite and proxy_pass but no luck. 
I have enable the upstream log and don't see the expected upstream URL

```
location /downloads {
  set $upstream_endpoint https://service2.com;
  proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint/app/$args;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
location /downloads {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass https://service2.com;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But i need to update the url while calling service2 endpoint. Updated the question as well..